# Custom AlertDialog.Builder adding custom button event click

Tags: android, dialog

On my Custom "Alert Dialog" I am having a dilemma of setting the onclick on the button that I have declared on xml.

This code gave me a null pointer exception which have been confirmed that there is an actual alertDialog after this was implemented

```
close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

LayoutInflates after an item is clicked on the ListView.

My question is "How do you set custom xml onClickListeners to buttons on a custom AlertDialog?"

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.data1);
    ImageView image = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.temp_book);
    Button summary, confirm, close;
    summary = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Summary);
    confirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmCD);
    close = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeCD);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(layout);

    close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alertDialog = builder.create();

    alertDialog.show();
```

Log Error

```
02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at test.list.A_Test4Activity.onListItemClick(A_Test4Activity.java:532)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1058)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2514)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3168)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)

02-28 15:13:28.385: E/AndroidRuntime(6763):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is the `close` button in your `Dialog` custom layout that you inflate?

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder builder = null; & AlertDialog alertDialog = null; 
Are declared globally.

Comment: it inflates on a listview click of a selected item.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Is your `close` button in the dialog or in the activity?

Comment: The close button is in the Alert Dialog.

Comment: Then search for the close `Button` in the inflated layout like you did for `text` and `image` : `close = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.closeCD);` (I see that you have other buttons , if they are also in the dialog then search for them in `layout`)

Comment: Thank you could you put that last comment in the answer so I can mark that as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing any stacktraces with the exception I would say that you don't look where you should be looking for the `Button` *close*. If you set the layout for your `AlertDialog`  to a custom layout that you inflate or a code built `View` then you have to do `findViewById(R.id.Id_of_button)` on that `View` that you set as the `AlertDialog` content.

**EDIT:**

The *close* `Button` is `null`(and throwing a `NullPointerException` when calling a method on it) because you have to search for the `Button` in the layout that was previously inflated and used as the `AlertDialog` content:

```
close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.closeCD);
```

Don't forget about the *summary* and *confirm* `Buttons` if they are also in the inflated layout.

Comment: I have done so. To avoid confusion I will post out the code I am currently using as well as the as the log error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `alertDialog` is null. It should be created before the OnClickListener:

```
alertDialog = builder.create();

close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
});

alertDialog.show();
```